# Solve the screened Poisson equation $(\Delta-\lambda^2) u(\vec r)=-c$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

I wish to solve this PDE in 3 dimensions

$$(\Delta-\lambda^2) u(\vec r)=-c$$

where $\lambda$ and $c$ are real and $c$ is a constant. The function $u$ is defined in a closed volume and boundaries conditions are given for $u$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screened_Poisson_equation) solve the problem assuming that $u$ and its derivatives vanish at infinite, which is wrong in my case. But it could be a good way to start maybe. So the solution with this assumption is

$$
u(\vec r) = \int d^3r' \frac{e^{-\lambda |\vec r - \vec r'| }}{4 \pi |\vec r - \vec r'|}
$$

Then I fail to integrate this. Either cartesian or spherical coordinates, I am stuck immediately.

I also tried to Fourier transform the equation using $u(\vec r)=\int d^3 q~~  \tilde{u}(\vec q) e^{-i \vec q \vec r}$ which leads us to

$$
(q^2-\lambda^2)\tilde{u}(\vec q)=-c ~\delta(\vec q) \\
\\
\tilde{u}(\vec q)=-c ~ \delta (\vec q) \frac{1}{q^2 - \lambda ^2} 
\\
u(\vec r)=-c \int d^3q~~\delta (\vec q) \frac{1}{q^2 - \lambda ^2} e^{-i \vec q \vec r} \\
\\
u(\vec r)=\frac{c}{\lambda^2}
$$

Which isn't correct obviously.

Comment: the ft of the delta function is a constant

Comment: Yes but the ft of the constant $c$ is a delta function, hence my delta... no?

Comment: u need  1.) the greens function of the possoin equation and 2.)  integrate it afterwards over the  ( constant) charge denisity. Just follow excatly the steps in the wiki article.

Comment: Problem is I can't get through all the steps, particularly when the triple integral is reduced into a single integral. Even though I would be stuck because I can't solve the last integral. Moreover the derivation assumes "u and its derivatives vanish at large r" which is wrong in my case. I work in a closed volume with given u at the boundaries. Does it mean I can't perform a ft?

Comment: There are ways to include other boundary conditions. I'm not an expert in this field, but in the end you have to fit some inner solution to some outer solution. You might for example consult the book of Jackson about electodynamics.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edited to make my boundary conditions more clear.

Comment: I am deleting this question if you don't mind, and create a new one much more precise.

Comment: David, what are the boundary conditions and the domain?